# reload data in p:dataTable at page reload

Tags: jsf, primefaces, refresh

I have the simpliest version of primefaces' DataTable (without sorting, pagination etc.) and controller class which is responsible for providing data to html page. 'cars' is collection passed to p:datatable as value attribute:

```
<p:dataTable id="dtid" var="car" value="#{someController.cars}" />


@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SomeController {

  @Inject
  SomeService dataProvider;

  private Collection<Car> cars;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    cars = dataProvider.getCars();
  }

  public Collection<Car> getCars() { 
    return cars;
  }
```

I want to ensure that collection of cars in reloaded every time i hit "refresh" button on my webpage. init() method is invoked only once, while the page is being loaded for the first time. How to achieve this in the simpliest way? To make things clear: I do not want to change scope to @RequestScope or anything else.

Thanks in advance,

P.

Comment: Why do you want to have it sessioncoped if you want it to be refreshed on each 'get' to a page? Why?

Comment: Because in the future there will be more private fields in controller which should have some state after page reloading: e.g. first i select some data from table (selected row is cached in controller's private field) and I click some button with non-ajax behaviour which reloads page. After that I have detailed information about data from selected row. Probably it's wrong and you have some better idea to achieve this?

Comment: Design is wrong. You can use a session scoped bean for the fields that need longer scope and a viewscoped one for the data. You can inject that in the bean with the longer scope.

Comment: I gave a shot to RequestScoped and it apparently worked well but after that I had an issue which had no workaround and finally forced me to return to SessionScoped and control refreshing by myself. Anyway, thanks for your comment, it way very useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "F5", you could add preRenderViewEvent in f:event tag and set init method as listener? Altough i also don't understand why you use session scoped bean in first place and this is kinda hacky.

Comment: According to comment I've just wrote under my previous post I had to use your solution. Thanks!